# Jenkins ClearCase UCM Plugin Failing While Rebasing

Tags: jenkins, rebase, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to run ClearCase Build with Jenkins ClearCase UCM Plugin version 1.7.1
Build is Running on a Windows Jenkins Slave on Which ClearCase Client is installed and Jenkins Service to Slave has access to ClearCase.

Below is the configuration I have filled in ClearCase Plugin

```
Stream - DevStream@\PVOB_TEST1  ( A Dev child Stream under an Integration Stream )
Load Modules - Modifiable
Polling - Poll Self
Promotion Level - Any
Component - TEST@\PVOB_TEST1
Use Newest Baseline - Tick Marked
```

When I checkin something in my view which is created on DevStream and create a baseline on the Dev Stream, the polling picks the change and build is started, but it fails with below error:

```
[CCUCM] Getting snapshotview
[CCUCM] Rebasing development stream (DevViewName) against parent stream (DevStream) Failed
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.praqma.util.execute.AbnormalProcessTerminationException: cleartool: Error: Can't rebase to baseline "Baseline1"
of component "TEST_SRC" because it was created in this stream.
cleartool: Error: Unable to rebase stream "DevStream".
Command: cleartool rebase -complete  -force -view DevViewName -baseline Baseline1@\PVOB_TEST1**
```

I am not sure why we are getting this error, I checkin something on my view of my DevStream then Create Baseline on Devstream but it is failing with above error.

I am new to ClearCase maybe I am missing something, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can't rebase to baseline "Baseline1" of component "TEST_SRC" because it was created in this stream

It is true you cannot rebase a stream with a baseline created on that very same stream.

Try and make sure your build is done with a sub-stream of Dev, one where you can rebase any baseline initially created on Dev, and which then be used by the build, set on said sub-stream.

Comment: Thanks, it helped and we were able to move ahead